# data[,] into list<string> or list<object> in c#

Tags: c#, arrays, list, object, casting

I have a array of two dimensions `object[,] data;`. I want to convert the first column of my object into a `list<string>` or a `list<object>`. here you have my code :

```
List<string> resultsFields = new List<string>();

object tmp = oRtx.get_ListFields(this.Instrument.ElementAt(i).Key.ToString(), RT_FieldRowView.RT_FRV_EXISTING, RT_FieldColumnView.RT_FCV_VALUE);
if (tmp != null)
{
    object[,] data = (object[,])Convert.ChangeType(tmp, typeof(object[,]));
    for (int j = 0; j < numItems; j++)
         resultsFields.Add(data[j, 0].ToString());
}
```

in this code, I add each items on `data[j, 0]` into my list. 
I would like to know if there is a faster method to convert the first column of my object (`[0]`) into a list

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only performance improvement i can see is creating the List<> with the specified capacity:

```
List<string> resultsFields = new List<string>(data.GetLength(0));
```